# ImageDataGenerator flow_from_dataframe with 2 outputs (y_col)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm developing a Functional API model, where:

- Input: Image
- Output:

  1. color classification (50 possibilities)
  2. shape classification (150 possibilities)

I'm fronting an issue regarding `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe` when passing the `y_col` argument as `["shape", "label"]`.
I have tried to use the `class_mode` argument as `raw`, `categorical` and all others.

When I set `categorical` the following error is retrieved:

> TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="['shape_std', 'label_std']" column values must be type string, list or tuple.

The code where the issue is happening is shown below:

```
# DataFrame Example:
                path  shape  label phase
     colorML19YI.jpg  15303   36   train  
     color4J3XI9.jpg  15303   36   train  
     colorMOYIAT.jpg  15303   36   train  
     colorJ6J6QR.jpg  15303   36   train  
     colorLGZ4OV.jpg  15303   36   train

self.batch_size = 32
self.phases = ['train', 'valid', 'test']
for i, phase in enumerate(self.phases):
            self.phase_gen.append(self.image_gen(df, phase, self.batch_size)

def image_gen(self, df, phase, batch_size):
    df_mod = df[df['phase']==phase]
    class_mode = 'categorical'
    y_col = ['shape', 'label', ['shape_std', 'label_std'], ["shape", "label"], ['shape_label2']]
    
    
    if phase == 'train':
        phase_iter = ImageDataGenerator(
                                        rotation_range=20,
                                        zoom_range=0.15,
                                        width_shift_range=0.2,
                                        height_shift_range=0.2,
                                        shear_range=0.15,
                                        horizontal_flip=True,
                                        fill_mode="nearest"
        ).flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df_mod,
            directory=self.imgs_dir,
            x_col='path',
            y_col=y_col[2],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            seed=1,
            shuffle=True,
            class_mode=class_mode,

        )
    elif phase == 'test':

            phase_iter = ImageDataGenerator(
                                        rotation_range=20,
                                        zoom_range=0.15,
                                        width_shift_range=0.2,
                                        height_shift_range=0.2,
                                        shear_range=0.15,
                                        horizontal_flip=True,
                                        fill_mode="nearest"
        ).flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df_mod,
            directory=self.imgs_dir,
            x_col='path',
            y_col=y_col[2],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            seed=1,
            shuffle=False,
            class_mode=None,

        )               

    else:
        phase_iter = ImageDataGenerator(#rescale=1.0/255.0
        ).flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df_mod,
            directory=self.imgs_dir,
            x_col='path',
            y_col=y_col[2],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            seed=1,
            shuffle=True,
            class_mode=class_mode,

        )
    return phase_iter
```

Someone could help me with it? Or have a clear idea of what if might be happen?

Comment: `shape_std` and `label_std` column values seems to be float32. Is it true?

Comment: No, when I'm generating the DataFrame there is a str converstion (df.astype(str)).
So all columns have as type 'object'.
What is strange is that when I'm just one variable as "y_col" the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe works well.

Comment: you have passed `shape_std` and `label_std` here => `y_col=y_col[2]`. But you have mentioned you are trying to pass `["shape", "label"]` as target column. Did you mean to set `y_col=y_col[3]`? Since `["shape", "label"]` is the 4th element in `y_col`  array. and please add the `df.info()` statement output to see how much data of what type you have.